# Electron.js App Fails to Generate PDF with jsPDF on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jspdf

#### Body:

I'm working on an Electron.js application that should generate a PDF using jsPDF when a button is clicked. The application runs without issues until I attempt to generate the PDF, at which point nothing happens. Additionally, I'm seeing error messages in the console related to Vulkan driver compatibility and VSync parameters.

##### Issue:

The 'Generate PDF' button click does not trigger the PDF generation as expected, and the following errors are logged in the console:

```
TU: error: ../src/freedreno/vulkan/tu_knl.cc:232: device /dev/dri/renderD128 (i915) is not compatible with turnip (VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER)
[ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 1 times!
```

These errors suggest a potential issue with the Vulkan driver and Electron's display synchronization.

##### Code Snippet:

Here's the relevant part of my `renderer.js`:

```js
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
const jsPDF = require('jspdf');


const generatePDF = () => {
  // ... code to collect form data ...
  const pdf = new jsPDF();
  // ... code to add content to PDF ...
  pdf.save('output.pdf');
};

document.getElementById('generatePdf').addEventListener('click', generatePDF);
```

---

##### What I've Tried:

- Ensuring that the paths to assets and save locations are correct.
- Checking permissions for file system access.

##### Question:

What could be causing the PDF generation to fail upon button click within an Electron.js environment, and how can I resolve the Vulkan driver and VSync parameter errors that appear in the console?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!